# How can I create a lightbox/microfilm effect in beamer slides?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tcolorbox, fun

I'm putting together a `beamer` presentation, and in a moment of madness I had the idea to give it a sort of lightbox/microfilm/transparency effect, sort of like [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/pdaaZWVyqHVnc4PCA) or [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/yhqkvJCGQvg1VFTh7) or [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/fzCaRdfxhVZy4DGMA). I tend to keep my slides very simple, so this is new territory for me. The only thing I can think to do is some sort of `tikz` gradient, but that doesn't really get me what I want:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [black!20] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\path [pattern color=black!30]
(-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\tcbvignette{fade in=black}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That gives you more of a picture frame effect with mitered corners, as here:

[image]

Is there another approach I can be taking? Is this even within the limits of `tikz`?